# Java regex all characters except last

Tags: regex

I want to place a dash after every letter but my regex place a dash at the end too. How can I improve my regex?

```
String outputS = dnaString.replaceAll("(.{1})", "$1-");
```

Comment: The dot matches any character but a newline - are you sure you need to insert a space after, say `,`? Check `outputS = dnaString.replaceAll("[\\p{L}\\p{M}](?!$)", "$0-");`.

Comment: Can you remove the `java` tag?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
(.)(?!$)
```

You can use this.Replace by `$1`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gT6vU5/11

`(?!$)` uses negative lookahead to state that do not capture a character which is at end of string.

Comment: Thanks! Can you please explain me `(?!$)`

Comment: `(?!X)` matches X, via zero-width negative lookahead

Answer (score 3):

Without regex (that is faster):

```
String[] nucleotides = dnaString.split("");
String outputS;

int seqLength = nucleotides.length;

if (seqLength > 1) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(nucleotides[0]);

    for (int i = 1; i < seqLength; i++) {
       sb.append("-");
       sb.append(nucleotides[i]);
    }

    outputS = sb.toString();
} else {
    outputS = dnaString;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*I know this is an old question, but for completeness and future reference I would like to add this answer.*

In Java 8 you can also use:

```
String.join("-",dnaString.toCharArray());
```

Explanation:

```
String.join(delimiter,objects...);
String.join(delimiter,array);
String.join(delimiter,Iterable);
```

These are used to join all objects to a single string with the delimiter as separator.

```
dnaString.toCharArray();
```

This is a method to get a String as an char array.

Answer (score 0):

This replaces all **special characters** with **underscore** '_' except the last occurence of a special character in the string.

```
String name = "one-of-the dummy$ string:i.txt";  // input
name = name.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9](?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])", "_");
System.out.println(name); 

//input: one-of-the dummy$ string:i.txt
//output: one_of_the_dummy__string_i.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This

```
(.)\B
```

doesn't match the last char.

See https://regex101.com/r/p0Z0zA/1

So, in your case, should be:

```
String outputS = dnaString.replaceAll("(.{1})\\B", "$1-");
```

*Credits to pigreco.*